# Добавление новых рядов и колонок в таблицу при нажатии кнопки

Tags: javascript

По нажатию на кнопку добавляется каждый раз только 1 соответствующий элемент. А надо, чтобы каждый раз добавлялся новый элемент с сохранением вложенности. То есть, при нажатии 1 раз на Add row создаётся 1 ряд, потом 2 раза нажимаю Add col и создаются 2 колонки в ЭТОМ ЖЕ ряду. Потом нажимаю снова Add row - и создаётся новый ряд и т.д.

```js
let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

let row = document.createElement('tr');
let col = document.createElement('td');


function addRow(){
  row.innerHTML = 'Row';
  table.appendChild(row);
}
function addCol(){
  col.innerHTML = 'Column';
  table.appendChild(col);
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
table tr {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

table td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addRow()">Add row</button>
<button onclick="addCol()">Add cell</button>
<table>

</table>
```

Comment: А почему вы `td` добавляете в `table`, а не в `tr` ? И вы никак не запоминаете выбор `tr` строки, чтобы туда добавлять `td` колонку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

let row;

function addRow() {
  row = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(row);
}

function addCol() {
  if (!row) {
    return row;
  }
  let col = document.createElement('td');
  col.innerHTML = 'Column';
  row.appendChild(col);
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

table tr {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

table td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addRow()">Add row</button>
<button onclick="addCol()">Add cell</button>
<table>

</table>
```

Comment: Вставлять в `tr` текст - не самая лучшая идея)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, как бы да, но вопрос не в этом

Comment: Вот теперь гораздо лучше! +1